# How to initialize a array with precompiler In C Programming Language

Tags: c, initialization, precompile

I want to initialize a array.
But ı have two different initial values in compile time.
So I want to do it in precompile time.
My code is

```
static const U8 userFont[8][8] =
{   
#if (LCD_LANGUAGE == LANG_1)
    { 0x0E, 0x09, 0x09, 0x1D, 0x09, 0x09, 0x0E, 0x00 }, 
    { 0x03, 0x0E, 0x11, 0x10, 0x10, 0x11, 0x0E, 0x00 }, 
    { 0x09, 0x06, 0x0F, 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x0F, 0x00 }, 
    { 0x0E, 0x11, 0x10, 0x10, 0x15, 0x0E, 0x04, 0x00 }, 
    { 0x11, 0x0E, 0x11, 0x10, 0x10, 0x11, 0x0E, 0x00 }, 
    { 0x19, 0x06, 0x09, 0x04, 0x02, 0x09, 0x06, 0x00 }, 
    { 0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03 },     
    { 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01 }      
#elif (LCD_LANGUAGE == LANG_2)
    { 0x0A, 0x00, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x0E, 0x00 },     
    { 0x04, 0x00, 0x1E, 0x04, 0x04, 0x04, 0x1E, 0x00 },     
    { 0x0A, 0x00, 0x0E, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x0E, 0x00 },     
    { 0x0E, 0x11, 0x10, 0x10, 0x11, 0x0E, 0x04, 0x00 },     
    { 0x0F, 0x10, 0x10, 0x0E, 0x01, 0x1E, 0x04, 0x00 },     
    { 0x0E, 0x00, 0x0F, 0x10, 0x17, 0x11, 0x0F, 0x00 },     
    { 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03 },     
    { 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01 }  

#endif
};
```

But I get this error :
"expected an expression". 
Error given at the end of array.
So how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

A couple of questions:

1. Have you defined the type `U8` with something like `typedef unsigned char U8;`?
2. Have you defined `LCD_LANGUAGE` as either `LANG_1` or `LANG_2`?

The reason I ask is because this little snippet below compiles and runs just fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef unsigned char U8;
#define LCD_LANGUAGE LANG_1
static const U8 userFont[8][8] =
{
#if (LCD_LANGUAGE == LANG_1)
    { 0x0E, 0x09, 0x09, 0x1D, 0x09, 0x09, 0x0E, 0x00 },
    { 0x03, 0x0E, 0x11, 0x10, 0x10, 0x11, 0x0E, 0x00 },
    { 0x09, 0x06, 0x0F, 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x0F, 0x00 },
    { 0x0E, 0x11, 0x10, 0x10, 0x15, 0x0E, 0x04, 0x00 },
    { 0x11, 0x0E, 0x11, 0x10, 0x10, 0x11, 0x0E, 0x00 },
    { 0x19, 0x06, 0x09, 0x04, 0x02, 0x09, 0x06, 0x00 },
    { 0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03 },
    { 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01 }
#elif (LCD_LANGUAGE == LANG_2)
    { 0x0A, 0x00, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x0E, 0x00 },
    { 0x04, 0x00, 0x1E, 0x04, 0x04, 0x04, 0x1E, 0x00 },
    { 0x0A, 0x00, 0x0E, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x0E, 0x00 },
    { 0x0E, 0x11, 0x10, 0x10, 0x11, 0x0E, 0x04, 0x00 },
    { 0x0F, 0x10, 0x10, 0x0E, 0x01, 0x1E, 0x04, 0x00 },
    { 0x0E, 0x00, 0x0F, 0x10, 0x17, 0x11, 0x0F, 0x00 },
    { 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03 },
    { 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01 }
#endif
};
int main (void) {
    printf ("0x%02x 0x%02x\n", userFont[0][0], userFont[2][2]);
    return 0;
}
```

producing:

```
0x0e 0x0f
```

Answer (score 1):

LANG_1 AND LANG_2 is enum so in procompile time this objects are invalid.
So I replace wtih integral values my problem is solved.
Thanks.